# DC series machine

Tags: dc-motor, torque, electric-machine

What is the different between electrical and mechanical torque? and How to find the mechanical torque if electrical torque is given?

Comment: They are equal when there is no acceleration except mechanical includes friction & other losses.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical torque is the torque exerted on the rotor by the magnetic field. Mechanical torque is the torque delivered by the motor shaft to the load. Mechanical torque is electrical torque minus the mechanical losses. Mechanical losses are the bearing friction, the friction of the brushes and the aerodynamic drag on the turning rotor. Those mechanical losses are present when the motor is running with nothing connected to the shaft. They can be calculated it you know the no-load current and the resistance of the windings and brushes.

Comment: Thank you very much @charles .